# Outlook OnSend App raises error (in console log) after successful execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling, outlook

I'm developing an OnSend App for Outlook, which *seems* to be working fine

But, I can see an error is raised, visible in the F12 console log, reproduced below; it doesn't seem to affect anything i.e. the App is performing as expected, but as the error is not occurring in the App code, I don't know what it means; help!

Is it to do with timing issues? I know the main App function (validateEmail) finishes before the callback function(s) ...

````
addNotificationMessageAsyncApiMethod.ts:86 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'extension' of null
    at addNotificationMessageAsyncApiMethod.ts:86
    at tslib.es6.js:102
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:83)
    at i (tslib.es6.js:73)```
````

Comment: Have you tried to look at the source code of the addNotificationMessageAsyncApiMethod.ts file on line 86 as stated in the error message? Did you try to validate the manifest file before running the add-in?

Comment: I've validated the manifest OK (using npx in the command line); and yes, I've looked at the source code, but it doesn't mean anything to me; I'm pretty sure the error is triggered by the addAsync method (mailboxItem.notificationMessages.addAsync('Send Blocked', { type: 'errorMessage', message: myMessage })) - as I get no error if I comment this line out

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer my own question: in the On-Send, the called function must return asyncContext.completed True or False; in an attempt to ensure the Notification message was refreshed correctly, I was using removeAsync, which caused my problem; resolution was to use replaceAsync instead of addAsync; interface documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessages?view=outlook-js-preview